# Socket.io - listen events in separate routes?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, koa2

How can I listen events in separate routes? [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653617/socket-io-listen-events-in-separate-files-in-node-js) is similar to what I am trying to do. For instance:

```
import Koa from 'koa'
import serve from 'koa-static'
import Router from'koa-router'
import views from 'koa-views'
import socket from 'socket.io'
import http from 'http'
import config from'./config'

const app = new Koa()
const router = new Router()

const server = http.createServer(app.callback())
const io = new socket(server)

app.use(async function (ctx, next) {
  ctx.io = io
  await next()
})

const test1 = async(ctx, next) => {
  ctx.io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected - event 1')
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('user disconnected')
    })
    socket.on('Event1', (data) => {
      console.log('Event1')
    })
  })

  await ctx.render('test1', {});
}

const test2 = async(ctx, next) => {
  ctx.io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log('a user connected - event 2')
    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('user disconnected')
    })
    socket.on('Event2', (data) => {
      console.log('Event2')
    })
  })

  await ctx.render('test2', {});
}

router
  .get('/', function (ctx, next) {
    ctx.body = 'Hello World!';
  })
  .get('/test1', test1)
  .get('/test2', test2)

app.use(serve(config.static_dir.root))
app.use(views(__dirname + config.template.path, config.template.options))

app
  .use(router.routes())
  .use(router.allowedMethods())

server.listen(config.server.port)
```

They works ok but buggy - when you **refresh** browser 3 times for `'/test1'`, io instance will be **repeated**, so I will get **repeated** result below:

```
a user connected - event 1
a user connected - event 1
a user connected - event 1
```

I guess I must have missed something or doing it wrong.

Any ideas?

Comment: destory the socket on disconnection.

Comment: @tbking how do I destroy it?

Comment: Sorry, scratch that. Not needed

Comment: Socket.IO doesn't have routes. If you only want a Socket.IO connection to be made when the user opens `/chat` in their browser, you need to make a separate/distinct template for that route that will open a connection.

Comment: @robertklep that makes sense. but why this package seems to have routes https://github.com/kudos/koa-websocket - it is based on ws package and i assume it should be the same for socket.io?

Comment: @teelou that's a package that implement some sort of routing on top of WebSockets. Perhaps there are similar packages that do the same based on Socket.IO, but it's not something that Socket.IO itself supports.

Comment: @robertklep yep that is one but it is outdated https://github.com/koajs/koa.io it is for Koa < 2.

Comment: @teelou any reason why you can't use `koa-websocket`? Perhaps only specifically for `/chat` if the rest of your app depends on Socket.IO

Comment: @robertklep these third party packages are unreliable and they might die one day. So I thought it would be better to have your own packages.

Comment: @teelou but you're using `koa`, `socket.io` and a whole bunch of other packages. Why wouldn't they die? Also, packages hardly ever get deleted from the NPM repository, so even if they become unmaintained, you can still use them in your projects.

Comment: @robertklep for an example - github.com/koajs/koa.io you can't use it in Koa2. That means you will get stuck with the old stuff - as you can't upgrade. It is better to do it directly from the source.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Namespace in sockets can be used to connect to a different route than `/`. https://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#custom-namespaces

Example:

```
io.of('/chat').on('connection', function(socket){
  console.log('someone connected');
});
```

---

Move this code out of the chat middleware. It should execute only once. Just put it out side the function and it should work.

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
   console.log('a user connected')
   socket.on('disconnect', () => {
      console.log('user disconnected')
   })
   socket.on('chat.message', (msg) => {
      console.log('message: ' + msg)
      io.emit('chat.message', msg)
   })
});
```

To make socket file serve on a different route than default, use `path` config while creating the io instance.

Example:

```
const io = new socket(server, { path: '/chat', serveClient: false });
```

more info here: https://socket.io/docs/server-api/#new-server-httpserver-options

Comment: i know that. but i just want to have it on certain routes.

Comment: @teelou SocketIO is route-less.

Comment: can you give me an example please?

Comment: it does not work. I get an error on my browser console - `Uncaught ReferenceError: io is not defined`

Comment: You are using `io` before adding this line. Move this line upwards.

Comment: `You are using io before adding this line. ` - what line?

Comment: that's what I did.

Comment: @tbking they mean `io` isn't defined _client side_, because that's what `path` does: it changes the path of the client-side library (and also its endpoint). So that got changed, but they didn't actually change the `<script src='/socket.io/socket.io.js'>`, resulting in errors.

Comment: Oh crap! Thanks @robertklep, I missed the word "browser". Yes, @teelou you need to change the path on client side to be `/chat` instead of `socket.io`.

Comment: @tbking but I'm going to guess that that isn't the actual problem that they want to solve anyway.

Comment: You are right, updated the answer to include namespaces. Which is what I think the OP is looking for.